# Is $\left|\left[\frac{1}{7,000,000,000},1\right]\right|<\left|[0,1]\right|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My question concerns the cardinality of two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. It feels very naive, but, isn't $\left[\dfrac{1}{7,000,000,000},1\right]$ "smaller" than $[0,1]$? I think that this is dependent upon one's set theory axioms, but I'd like an answer from the most common axiomatic models.

After consulting Wikipedia, I've seen that you must show there is *only* an injective function from $B$ to $A$ to prove that $|A|>|B|$. Such a function is obvious: $f:A\to B$ with $x\mapsto x$. The hard part seems showing there is *not* a bijective function.

I don't know how to do that, but I think I might be able to figure out why I don't know how to do that. It seems like the continuum hypothesis is at work here: I am trying to find some sort of cardinality, $X$, such that $\aleph_0 < |X| < 2^{\aleph_0}$. This is because it would be intuitive that any subset of the real number system which is an interval would have a larger cardinality than $\aleph_0$. Similarly, I'm trying to find a similar cardinality $Y$ such that $X<Y$.

**What's going on here?**

Comment: For any $a < b$ finite reals, $f:[a,b] \rightarrow [0,1]$ sends $x \mapsto \frac{x-a}{b-a}$ is a homeomorphism of the usual topologies, and in particular a bijection of sets. I can't imagine many axiomatic models wouldn't accomodate such a map.

Comment: So, @ABlumenthal, $f$ is a bijection from $[a,b]$ to $[0,1]$ with $a<b$ and $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$? Hence, the two sets are of equivalent cardinality?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: Could someone clarify on what the phrase "homeomorphism of the usual topologies" means? I did not understand that.

Comment: This function is a continuous bijection with a continuous inverse when both intervals are equipped with the usual topology, i.e. subspace Euclidean topology from the reals, so the function is in fact a homeomorphism.

Comment: In this context you may interpret it as saying simply that $f$ is a continuous bijection whose inverse is also continuous.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I understand now.

Comment: Just to clarify something: 'size' in the intuitive sense has no bearing on cardinality, in a catastrophic way. An example is the cantor set (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), which has cardinality of the continuum and yet has "size zero" in the most natural sense (that of Lebesgue measure, which is a kind of rigorous model of the notion of 'size' for (most) subsets of the real line).

Comment: Maybe, instead of "cardinality" you want to compare the "length" of the two sets.  By that measure one of them is, indeed, "smaller" than the other.

Comment: @ABlumenthal: Most in what sense? Assuming the axiom of choice the set of Lebesgue measurable sets is not even measurable in the product measure in $2^\mathbb R$. That's like saying that most the elements of $\mathbb R$ are in a specific Vitali set.

Comment: See the Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein Theorem in Wikipedia. You have as you say an obvious injection of the 'smaller' interval into the'bigger' interval and it is easy to get a continuous injection of the 'bigger' interval to the 'smaller' interval. I suggest this because if you replace the 'smaller' interval with the real line $\mathbb R$ and keep $[\ 0\ ,\ 1\ ]$ you do not have a continuous function that will do it, but you can use $\tan$ or $\arctan$ with appropriate arguements to get a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $(\ 0\ ,\ 1\ )$  and then you have to do something about the endpoints.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was being facetious. I should probably have said something along the lines of "this construction is elementary (i.e. simple) and does not invoke the axiom of choice".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All intervals have the same cardinality as the reals $2^{\aleph_0}$.  A Blumenthal has given you a bijection between any closed interval and $[0,1]$.  Then you can find a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ (how can two points matter?) and between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb R$.  It is true that the length of the intervals is different, but the cardinality is not.

According to the continuum hypothesis, known to be consistent with ZFC but not required, there are no sets $X$ such that $\aleph_0 < |X| < 2^{\aleph_0}$, so don't look too hard for them.

Comment: Actually, how *do* you find a bijection between $[0, 1]$ and $(0, 1)$?

Comment: @JoeZeng:   You find two chains of points and shift them down the line.  I'll just do one end:  $f(0)=1/3, f(1/3^n)=1/3^{(n+1)}, f(x)=x$ for $x \ne 1/3^k$.  The other end is similar.

Comment: Didn't think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just to supplement Ross’ already-very-clear answer. In what follows, I shall assume that you know some basic measure theory.

Let $ \mu $ be the standard Borel measure defined on the Borel $ \sigma $-algebra $ \mathcal{B} $ of the closed interval $ [0,1] $. Define a quasi-ordering $ \preceq $ on $ \mathcal{B} $ as follows:
$$
\forall B_{1},B_{2} \in \mathcal{B}: \quad B_{1} \preceq B_{2} \stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} \mu(B_{1}) \leq \mu(B_{2}).
$$
If $ B_{1} $ and $ B_{2} $ are sub-intervals of $ [0,1] $, then $ \preceq $ is simply a comparison of their lengths.

Define also a quasi-ordering $ \leqslant $ on $ \mathcal{B} $ as follows:
\begin{align}
\forall B_{1},B_{2} \in \mathcal{B}: \quad
                             B_{1} \leqslant B_{2}
&\stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} |B_{1}| \leq |B_{2}| \\
&\iff                        (\exists f)(\text{$ f: B_{1} \to B_{2} $ is injective}).
\end{align}

The point to note is:

> The quasi-ordered set $ (\mathcal{B},\preceq) $ is not isomorphic to the quasi-ordered set $ (\mathcal{B},\leqslant) $ in the category of quasi-ordered sets.

Comment: Is this a very precise way of mathematically qualifying the statement that 'length' and 'cardinality' are two _very_ different concepts?

Comment: Yes. Although ‘length’ and ‘cardinality’ offer ways of *comparing* Borel subsets of $ [0,1] $, they are mutually incompatible.

Comment: Your skill of exposition is beautiful.